# Does the term phase difference apply only for sinusoidal waves?

Tags: waves, definition

This question may sound dumb, (it will to me, hopefully, in a day or two!), but does the term phase difference apply  *only* for sinusoidal waves?

Wikipedia defines 'phase' as the following:

> Phase in sinusoidal functions or in waves has two different, but
>   closely related, meanings. One is the initial angle of a sinusoidal
>   function at its origin and is sometimes called phase offset or phase
>   difference. Another usage is the fraction of the wave cycle that has
>   elapsed relative to the origin.

I'm confused about this specific part:

> Another usage is the fraction of the wave cycle that has elapsed
>   relative to the origin

Can this definition apply for any wave function, or just sinusoidal ones?

Comment: Yes it can apply to any waveform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this definition is useful for any kind of cyclic phenomenon, why not?
Think for example of 'phases of the moon'.

In the case of *fourier analysis* however, 'phase' usually means: phase of a sinusoidal component, not the phase of the waveform that is being analyzed.